# My scroll view does not responding i can not scroll down

Tags: xamarin.forms

In my XAML file, I used scroll view for scroll down but it does not work I can not find any issue where I did a couple of extra things here one is I add pull to refresh nuget and use it and I create a theme content class and I inherited it with default content page. another command in content page is working but scroll view does not support

Here my Xaml file

```
<views:BaseContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView BackgroundColor="White">
        <controls:PullToRefreshLayout x:Name="PullToRefreshLayout" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshCommand="RefreshPatientDetailsPage">

        <StackLayout> 
        // some code
         </StackLayout>

    </controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</views:BaseContentPage.Content>
```

this is the Base content page I create

```
public abstract class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public readonly BaseViewModel BaseViewModel;

    protected bool IsNavigated;

    public BaseContentPage(BaseViewModel baseViewModel)
    {
        BaseViewModel = baseViewModel;
    }        
    protected abstract override void OnAppearing();
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        IsNavigated = true;
    }       
}
```

I think this scroll view does not work because of the NuGet I put or it's the base content page

for android, I used this customer render

```
      public class SortPaneListViewRendererAndroid : ListViewRenderer
{
    public SortPaneListViewRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            var listView = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
            listView.DividerHeight = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try commenting `controls:PullToRefreshLayout` and see if it works

Comment: i did that but it does not work

Comment: Are you sure you have enough controls for the scroll to work in the first place?

Comment: yes, it has when I use small emulator it only shows part of that when I use long screen emulator it shows the all content

Comment: Are you sure you do not have renderers mapped to your scrollview?

Comment: i have three custom renders but only this apply to this page

Comment: public class SortPaneListViewRendererAndroid : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public SortPaneListViewRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
                var listView = Control as Android.Widget.ListView;
                listView.DividerHeight = 1;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191500/discussion-between-ish1104-and-g-hakim).

Comment: hakim you have any idea what went wrong here

Comment: I think you have some issue with your code, now I thought it would have been a renderer but I guess this could be something else (not sure what though yet)

Comment: yes i figure the problem it is because on of my render has scroll and i again called scroll in XAML that's the problem i solved it thanks

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Comment: @ish1104 I have added an answer take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this was happening is because you are nesting scrollable controls, Removing one of them will solve the issue